LUKS encrypted dual boot
I want to install Ubuntu as a secondary OS and I want to keep its contents private from my Windows 11 install. All of the tutorials I've found use GRUB. My question is will I be able to go into my UEFI settings and set the Windows boot manager to have priority over GRUB? I want it to boot into Windows automatically unless I press f10 and select Ubuntu/GRUB.
And finally can anyone walk me through the process for installing and encrypting? I have a live ISO ready to go and a 100GB partition that's separate from my Windows install. It's a brand new, Windows 11 laptop.

You can set grub to automatically boot Windows by default or boot what it booted the last time. The process of installing is simple enough. Used the advanced menu for encrypting.

The advanced menu only has the option to encrypt the whole disk, not one partition.

This question is similar to: How can I install Ubuntu encrypted with LUKS with dual-boot?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
